# Cassandra Delete Commit Log Files

Tags: cassandra

I have almost 200 GB of commit log files because the commitlog_total_space_in_mb was commented.I have enabled it and changed the path for commit log file,I still have 200 GB of commit log file at old location ,  I like to know When can I delete the Commit log files?

Answer (score 4):

If you changed locations for the commit logs C* wont manage old ones (providing you restarted the node since you made the change). You will have to delete them yourself. I am not familiar enough with scenario but to be safe you can do a repair to make sure every things where it should be and delete them after that.